# Automatically extracting files from archive before compilation

Tags: compiling, revision-control, directory, build-system, extract

I've got a LaTeX project in a Git repository which is being worked on using both TeX Live (Linux) and MiKTeX (Windows). The project has a very large number of `\includegraphics[...]{...}` statements for single files (both PDF and PNG), many of which cannot be combined because they are e.g. embedded in LaTeX `tabular` environments. Everything compiles just fine, but my current hosting solution has a set limit for the number of individual files the Git repository can have. In order to keep my project under this limit, **is there no way to add add a pre-compilation step which extracts a given archive to a given location?** If this project was handled using only Linux, I could e.g. write a [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) which does this and then calls the relevant LaTeX/BibTeX commands, but doing this in a way which also works seamlessly with Windows would be extremely difficult and would probably take more time to implement than simply extracting the archive manually each time.

### Target structure

For example, compilation currently depends on the following directory structure:

```
+-- content
|   +-- specimens
|   |   +-- specimen-1.pdf
|   |   +-- specimen-2.pdf
|   |   +-- specimen-3.pdf
|   |   +-- specimen-4.pdf
|   |   +-- specimen-5.pdf
|   |   +-- specimen-6.pdf
|   |   +-- ...
|   +-- experiment-setup.png
|   +-- stimuli.png
+-- mybib.bib
+-- cool-experiment.tex
+-- fun-conference.sty
```

### Source structure

The following structure is how it currently looks in the Git repository in order to keep the project under the file count limit:

```
+-- content
|   +-- experiment-setup.png
|   +-- specimens.zip
|   +-- stimuli.png
+-- mybib.bib
+-- cool-experiment.tex
+-- fun-conference.sty
```

Comment: If you are able to write a makefile then you should also be able to write a simple windows batch file that unzip a zip-file.

Comment: again, having to create and maintain one build process is time-consuming enough; learning horrible .bat file syntax and creating and maintaining a second build system based on it is worse than stupid.

Comment: I would understand your argument if you had a complicated build. But here you only want to unzip and then run a few tools. But if you want a script that works on both system either install make on windows. Or  write a lua script. This you can use on both systems. Check e.g. l3build.